# How get data JSON multi array via POST in php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Looking to get some help. I want to get data from json multi array with PHP POST method, if i use JSON without multi array, I can get that data. this is my Json :

```
{
    "total_record": "300",
    "data":
            [{
                    "guestid": "757",
                    "rsvid": "3706001",
                    "conf_no": "fnine-3706001",
                    "arrival_date": "2017-09-25 14:34:28",
                    "departure_date": "2017-09-26 11:18:35"
                },
                {
                    "guestid": "4835",
                    "rsvid": "3472001",
                    "conf_no": "fnine-3472001",
                    "arrival_date": "2018-03-28 00:00:00",
                    "departure_date": "2018-03-30 13:00:00"
                }]
}
```

for PHP code like below :

```
print_r($_POST);

$fieldpost1 = $this->post();
print_r($fieldpost1);

$fieldpost2 = json_decode($this->input->post(), true);
print_r($fieldpost2);
```

result :

```
Array ( ) Array ( )
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: controllers/Api.php

Line Number: 70

Backtrace:
```

Can anyone help me, if this method is not possible, maybe there are other ways I can do it in PHP or Codeigniter ?, thank you.

Comment: try to var_dump $this->post() instead of $_POST, you'll see the difference and Im sure you'll understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tge post method returns an associative array of the parameters from the browser
By definition its not a json string

Let's assume that the parameter sent by post is json, we can play with that :

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
```

Then this should work:

```
print_r($json);
```

To get the json as an array, then you should json decode $json, with the true parameter, to get an associative array and not an object

```
$jsonarray = array();
$jsonarray = json_decode($json, true);
```

now to print it,foreach is needed:

```
foreach ($jsonarray as $fieldpost1) {
print_r($fieldpost1);
}
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the True into your json decode

```
$json = json_decode($json);
print_r($json);

foreach ($json->data as $data)
{

        echo 'guestid : ' .$data->guestid .'<br/>';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in codeigniter `$this->input->post('keyword', TRUE);` method required `keyword`.
you didn't pass the keyword so that it will return `NULL` value.

if you want to get request body, use this

```
$requestBody = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the whole `$_POST` array to `json_decode()`.

Try `json_decode($this->input->post('json_field'));`